# Where can I find reference names to find out where to put my block?

Tags: magento

For example, I want to put my block on the product page before the description block. How would I find these reference names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, based on your question and subsequent comments, you are looking for a way to position blocks before other blocks in the layout?

If so, the layout system provides you with before and after block attributes, for this exact purpose.

The general use is to add a before or after attribute containing the block you would like to position - before or after.

**Before Example**

```
<block type="yourmodule/block_type" name="yourblock" before="the_block_name_to_position_before" />
```

**After Example**

```
<block type="yourmodule/block_type" name="yourblock" after="the_block_name_to_position_before" />
```

**Positioned before product description**

In your particular scenario, where you would like a block to be positioned before the product description block, you need a little extra xml due to how the product description block is being included into the layout:

```
<!-- file: app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout/local.xml -->
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="yourmodule/block_type" name="yourblock" template="yourmodule/template.phtml" before="product.description">
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

The important thing to note here though, in terms of you original question, is the use of the `before` attribute for positioning.

Answer (score 2):

In the Magento Control Panel set your `Current Configuration Scope` to a specific website. Then, under System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Debug` turn on Template Path Hints and Add Block Names to Hints.

After that, when you reload the page it will tell you what blocks to override to get the desired effect.

[image: The Developer Panel (after selecting a specific website scope)]

Comment: Okay, for example, if I wanted it after this `frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/description.phtml`  `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Description` then how would make XML look like?

Comment: @Strawberry It's not really what your original question seems to be asking, but search the xml for `product_view_description` (It's probably in *catalog.xml*.) Put a new block declaration after that, or override the template that is in the block declaration that's already there.

Comment: I'm just unclear oh how to actually use the information you gave me. So Would my reference look like this? `<reference name='product.view.description'>`?

Comment: @Strawberry might I suggest [a guide to layout xml](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/)?